# Downloading files which were stored using the storage facade in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, download, access-control

I've noticed that the method `Storage::download($path)` is not available until Laravel 5.6. I would rather not create symbolic links since this appears to me to defeat the purpose of using the storage facade, might as well save the file in the assets folder (not sure how correct I am in saying this).

My question is, how can I download a file that I have saved using the storage facade and not make the file publicly visible through a URL link?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$path = "/path/to/file/";
$filename = "my_file.pdf"
return response(Storage::disk('local')->get($path.$filename), 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', Storage::disk('local')
                ->mimeType($path.$filename)
);
```

---

Edit:

If to store you use:

```
$path=$request->file('file')->store('file');
```

that's going to store the file in the `storage/app/file` folder, with a name created by laravel. For example:

```
storage/app/file/7K5gIZvRVWbdBedRXEyVm5X1Ubz61vJZguFmERlT.jpeg
```

(Make sure the file has been stored).

And in DB you must save (I do not know how you're doing this, but it's the 'file' folder and the file name created by laravel):

```
file/7K5gIZvRVWbdBedRXEyVm5X1Ubz61vJZguFmERlT.jpeg
```

So, to download you have to make a route:

```
Route::get('/download', 'DownloadController@downloadFile')->name('download-file');
```

And a Controller method:

```
public function downloadFile()
{
     $path = // get the DB field

     return response(Storage::get($path), 200)
         ->header( 'Content-Type', Storage::mimeType($path) );
}
```

And you can add a link in a view:

```
<a href="{!! route('download-file') !!}" download>Download the file</a>
```

Comment: $path and $filename have to match the path and filename that were stored, also the disk. Could you post how you stored it?

Comment: I stored the file when it was uploaded like so `$path=$request->file('file')->store('file');` using the default disk which was configured as private with its root in storage/app. The path is being stored in a BD and this is what I'm using in the download action

Comment: I edited the answer with the data you have given. I do not know what the DB part is like, but what I'm going for is that you can do it by returning the file with the mimetype

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what I was doing but its not working, I confirmed that the file is being stored and that the path is being saved correctly in the database but still no luck :(